# Google Sheets converting Conditional Formatting to Apps Scripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I'm sure that there's not an easy way to do this, but I figured I would ask. I have a sheet that has a decent amount of conditional formatting on it, however, people that I share the sheet with have been copy/pasting and moving rows which aggravatingly disrupts the formatting. I am trying to convert to Scripting for them. The main thing is background colors based on other cell information.

ie: if Any cell from row 4 from column A-D has information in it then the K4 will be red. Once K4 has information inside it then the background will be white.

The conditional formatting I have is: =AND(OR(ISBLANK(A4)=FALSE,ISBLANK(B4)=FALSE,ISBLANK(C4)=FALSE,ISBLANK(D4)=FALSE),ISBLANK(K4)=TRUE).

The other is that when any cell has a certain term "LWOS" then the whole row has a purple background and strikethrough.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be helpful - https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script. You can use the values from cells and check if it contains anything, and if it does, just highlight it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know scripting is hard when you are new to it, so I understand you and decided I'm going to give you a code that should work with yours. And please do follow Endothermic_Dragon's recommendation into studying [Apps Script](http://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/apps-script) if you want to learn more.

Code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get active spreadsheet and sheet
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  // Get row and column of the current cell edited
  var editRow = e.range.getRow();
  var editColumn = e.range.getColumn();

  // If edited cell is below row 4:
  if(editRow > 3) { 
    // Get row and K cell for checking values later
    var rowRange = sheet.getRange("A" + editRow + ":D" + editRow)
    var rowValues = rowRange.getValues();
    var kCell = sheet.getRange("K" + editRow);
    var kValue = kCell.getValue();

    var rowHasValue = rowValues[0].some(el => !!el);
    var rowHasLWOS = rowValues[0].includes("LWOS");
    var kHasValue = kValue != "";

    // If edited column is in A-D
    if(editColumn < 5) { 
      // If we see a value on that row and K row doesnt have value 
      if(rowHasValue && !kHasValue){
        // Set K cell to red
        kCell.setBackground("red");
      }

      // If columns A-D of the edited row has LWOS 
      // (cell value is "LWOS", not cell containing LWOS)
      if (rowHasLWOS){ 
        // Set row to purple and strikethrough
        sheet.getRange(editRow + ":" + editRow).setBackground("purple").setFontLine("line-through");
      }
    }
    // If edited column is K
    if(editColumn == 11) { 
      // If row doesnt have LWOS, proceed with checking the K value
      if(!rowHasLWOS) {
        // If edited value of K has value
        if(kHasValue) { 
          // Set K to white
          sheet.getRange("K" + editRow).setBackground("white");
        }
        // If K value was deleted and A-D has values
        if(rowHasValue && !kHasValue) { 
          // Set K back to red
          sheet.getRange("K" + editRow).setBackground("red");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

This has comments on it so hopefully you can at least understand what the code does and how it works.

For more details, check the references you can study below.

**References:**

- [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)
- [Spreadsheet tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials)
- [Beginners guide by Ben Collins](https://www.benlcollins.com/apps-script/google-apps-script-beginner-guide/)

Comment: The "e.range.getRow" portion comes back to me with "range" not being defined. I've tried defining it a few different ways and no avail.

Comment: @JM, were you trying to run the function manually via editor? it becomes undefined because it gets the `e.range` from the edited cell. it is being triggered during edit thus `e.range` have value. if you just ran it on editor, it won't work.